# Roll a fair dice thrice, what is the probability of smallest recorded observation is $\geq$4.

Tags: probability

I wasn't sure how to solve it, so I tried to list all possible cases and came to the answer $\dfrac{27}{216}$ which solves to $\dfrac{3}{24}$.
Here 27 cases include 9 cases for 6, 5, and 4, and 216 are the total possible outcomes which we get from $6^3$.
I am unsure if I am missing out on something.

Comment: You are correct and your combinatoric argument is valid. There are ways to make you're method quicker instead of listing all possible cases explicitly (which  is oft infeasible). Consider looking up introductions to combinatorics if that isn't something already on your radar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am aware of combinatorics but it isn't my strong suit, since I wasn't sure of it, I tried this longer method. Although since I know the answer now, would it be  {( $3\choose 1$) * ($3\choose 1$) * ($3\choose 1$) divided by 216 ? I know because of the answer, but not sure as to why this would be the case?

Comment: On any fair dice the probability that you get $\geq 4$ is $1/2$ so probability that you get $\geq 4$ in all three rolls is $1/8$. That is same as $27/216$.

Comment: That is a valid way to express the problem @Alzebrian (noting $6^3 = 216$). It looks like you are getting the basics down, good luck moving forward!

Comment: @MathLover yes that was my first intuition, prolly the lack of sleep made me miss that it solves down to $\dfrac{1}{8}$ which is essentially 0.5*0.5*0.5

Comment: Especially when short on sleep, I like to simulate such combinatorial problems as a check on the logic. Here $1/8$ is correct:  R code `set.seed(2021); 
mean(replicate(10^6, min(sample(1:6, 3, rep=T)))>=4)` returns $ 0.125603,$ consistent with $1/8$ within the 95% margin of simulation error  $\pm 0.0007$
for a million iterations.